# rootogram() error when checking for overdispersion in GAM

Tags: r, gam

I have run the below GAM and am trying to plot a `rootogram()` using the `countreg` package to check for overdispersion, but get the error `Error in X[, pstart[i] - 1 + 1:object$nsdf[i]] <- Xp : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`.

I understand what the error message is telling me, that the length of two vectors/objects do not match, but am none the wiser as to how to fix it. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated? Has anyone had this problem previously, if so how did you fix it?

This may be arising due to a peculiarity in my data as I have never previously had a problem producing rootograms when using other datasets.

```
# I cannot fit a rootogram from the following GAM
> knots2 <- list(nMonth = c(0.5, 12.5))

> sup15 <- gam(Number ~ State + Virus + State*Virus + s(nMonth, bs = "cc", k = 12, by = Virus) + s(Time, k = 60, by = Virus), 
            data = supply.pad, 
            family = nb(), 
            method = "REML", 
            knots = knots2)

> root_nb <- rootogram(sup15, style = "hanging", plot = FALSE)
Error in X[, pstart[i] - 1 + 1:object$nsdf[i]] <- Xp : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length


# But can fit a rootogram from the below GAM. Note that these are different datasets but pretty much the same code.
> knots1 <- list(month = c(0.5, 12.5))

> gam10 <- gam(n ~ State + s(month, bs = "cc", k = 12) + s(time), 
             data = rhdv.gp.pad, 
             family = nb(), 
             method = "REML", 
             knots = knots1)

> root_nb1 <- rootogram(gam10, style = "hanging", plot = FALSE)
```